# How to implement submit button with type="button"

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I need to submit the form data to backend (using python flask), but I'm not allowed to use button with type="submit", I can only use a regular button (with type="button"), and implement the submit logic in Javascript. How to do this?

Comment: by adding click event listener and have the handler code use AJAX

Comment: If you have a `<button></button>` element (not a `<input type="button">`) ***without*** a `type` at all, and that `<button></button>` is within a `<form>`, that `<form>` will be submitted by default. No explicit event handling needed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `onclick` event on the `<button>` and the `<form>` [DOM submit method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)

```js
function submitForm() {
  let form = document.getElementById("simple-form");
  // do something here before submitting the form
  form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="simple-form">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <button id="btn-submit" type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```